# On the official AMP Website the Animations are showing console errors

Tags: amp-html

https://preview.amp.dev/documentation/examples/visual-effects/amp_story_animations
I don't know why but the animations are not working. Considering that AMP is from Google. I am not sure whether it is a problem only on my system or its is also faced by other people.

Comment: First, the page is `amp-story` - a special but slightly different flavor of AMP.  When I am in Chrome, it works as expected. Ditto for Mozilla. There is one console error: 404 on the favicon.